# Pgfplots. Как уменьшить число отметок на оси?

Tags: latex, графики

Есть график в pgfplots, как видно из рисунка ниже на нём очень часто стоят подписи на оси. Как сделать их меньше?

[image: График]

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$S(t)$,
    width = 750,
    height = 450,
    ymin = 0,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true]
    \addplot[line width = 1, color = red] table{plots/31.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Автокорреляционная функция}\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для задания меток в pgfplots у Вас есть несколько возможностей. Все дальнейшие опции, о которых я напишу, нужно помещать через запятую к другим опциям в окружении `axis`. И естественно, все это можно применить ко всем осям координат (`xtick`, `ytick`, `ztick`), хоть я и пишу примеры только с `xtick`.

Во-первых, Вы можете в явном виде перечислить все координаты, где нужны метки:

```
xtick={-300,-150,0,50,150,180,300},
```

Во-вторых, можно задать шаг для отображения меток по первым двум координатам в списке и обозначив конечное значение для меток (например, я установил шаг в 50 по `x`):

```
xtick={-300,-250,...,300},
```

Здесь следует заметить, что в документации настоятельно рекомендуют не использовать пробелы в этих конструкциях - должны быть только числа (можно и вещественные), разделители чисел - запятые и троеточие  (в последней конструкции).

В-третьих, в том случае, если к заданным таким образом меткам нужно добавить еще какую-то, то можно воспользоваться конструкцией:

```
extra x ticks = {21,42},
extra tick style={grid=major},
```

Здесь аргументом первой команды является список координат, в которых нужно добавить метки. Во второй команде мы явно указываем, что к этой метке надо "приклеить" большую черточку как и у других меток (`major`, и если есть сетка, то к этой координате также будет проведена линия сетки). Но можно указать и тип `minor`, тогда все зависит от настроек используемой сетки (как я понимаю, по умолчанию, сетка не проходит через минорные метки).

В дополнение к меткам и `major ticks`, можно еще задать мелкие черточки между метками. Вот они задаются просто указанием количества:

```
    minor x tick num = 5,
    minor y tick num = 10,
```

Дополнительные опции по оформлению осей (да и графиков в целом) нужно читать в официальном руководстве по пакету: ***pgfplots.pdf***, который у Вас должен быть в составе документации по LaTeX (например, в MikTeX его можно найти по адресу: "%MikTeX%\doc\latex\pgfplots\pgfplots.pdf", где %MikTeX% - это корневой каталог установки MikTeX). Также, можно найти этот документ на любом из серверов [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) (это такое большое сетевое сборище всех пакетов TeX).

Ну и пример с Вашим кодом (на всякий случай):

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$S(t)$,
    xtick={-300,-250,...,300},
    width = 750,
    height = 450,
    ymin = 0,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true]
    \addplot[line width = 1, color = red] table{plots/31.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Автокорреляционная функция}\label{}
\end{figure}
```